# How to run Bleachbit as root?

Tags: bleachbit

I have installed BleachBit 0.8.7. Would it be possible to kindly let me know if BleachBit can be run as administrator of my account?

Answer (score 3):

When you Install BleachBit it creates 2 entries.

- BleachBit
- BleachBit (as root)

Run the second entry and type your password.

Answer (score 2):

think i can help you out since i am using this software every day.

This site has a little info on how to set it up.

http://helpsite.org/bleachbit/

To install Bleachbit in Ubuntu :

> :~$ *sudo apt-get update*
>
> :~$ *sudo apt-get install bleachbit*

After install is complete in terminal type:

:~$ bleachbit for desktop

if you wanna clean with root priviligies.

> :~$ sudo bleachbit

Or you can open them from the Dash and run gui to open either one up.

I usually clean my system daily with desktop Bleachbit since cache and surfing or programming lots local machine before deployment to some where else.

Here is extensive info on how to or what to clean with Bleachbit Desktop or with root priviligies.

http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/documentation

In general you can thick mark all browsers that you are using. Firefox, Opera, SeaMonkey, Chrome etc etc. Except leave the thick mark out from passwords so you do not reinstall or re-type them on next time you surf like to any web mail or facebook, twitter etc.

On system no need to clean extensive files like memory, deep scans etc. Temp files are ok. Bash is just what you have typed in terminal it will clean them text cache out. If you use skype, pidgin, emphaty chat clients, you can clean them as well all.

System type is good to use caution so you do not clean things that your system is needing to operate normal ops or apps.

APT you can tick all of them, same on bash history.Chromium all except passwords. Deep-scan all except .DS_Store , Firefox all except passwords. Libreoffice all , Skype all System thick these > Cache, Clipboard,Recent documents list, Temporary files, Trash Thunderbird > All except passwords Thats all for Desktop bleachbit.

In root side, just thick these.

APT > All Deep Scan > Temporary Files System > Broken desktop files, Cache , Clipboard, Temp files, Trash

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Uri is correct.

By the way, BleachBit version 0.8.7 is very old, and there have been many important fixes since then. You can get Ubuntu .deb packages for the latest BleachBit 0.9.4 at  http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net