# Bleachbit 1.6 fails at "Running deep scan"

Tags: bleachbit

14.04. I just updated BleachBit from v. 1.0-x *(or similar, twas what Software Center installed about 2 months ago)*, to v. 1.6. What prompted the update was, 1.0 would fail (freeze, grey-out) at the *"Running deep scan"* operation... unfortunately now 1.6 behaves exactly the same, never recovers, need to Quit > Force Quit. BB does this even when running 'Preview' !!

The BB settings I have are the same as reco'd in this reply: https://askubuntu.com/a/488133/359427 -

```
On system no need to clean extensive files like memory, deep scans etc. Temp files are ok. Bash is just what you have typed in terminal it will clean them text cache out. If you use skype, pidgin, emphaty chat clients, you can clean them as well all.
System type is good to use caution so you do not clean things that your system is needing to operate normal ops or apps.
APT you can tick all of them, same on bash history.Chromium all except passwords. Deep-scan all except .DS_Store , Firefox all except passwords. Libreoffice all , Skype all System thick these > Cache, Clipboard,Recent documents list, Temporary files, Trash Thunderbird > All except passwords Thats all for Desktop bleachbit.
In root side, just thick these.
APT > All Deep Scan > Temporary Files System > Broken desktop files, Cache , Clipboard, Temp files, Trash
```

Upon install of this v. 1.6, I did NOT select 'shred freed space' or whatever that option was called, coz I suspected this may have been at the root of the 1.0 failing problem.

Running BB from terminal as root *[~$ sudo bleachbit]*, the last several lines of output before BB would freeze and the GUI would grey-out, are *(I added line breaks coz the paste from terminal removed them all)*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/GUI.py", line 759, in check_online_updates
    lambda: gobject.idle_add(self.cb_refresh_operations))
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/Update.py", line 146, in check_updates
    handle = opener.open(Common.update_check_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known</em>
```

^ that last line, following *URLERROR:*  was wrapped in <> but I removed coz it seemed they were making the message invisible here at askubuntu, at least in the preview (reading as html).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall it after purging the existing bleachbit ?

Comment: I suggest to be very cautious while using BleachBit (in root mode), since you can seriously damage your system beyond repair!! (Happened to me twice)

Answer (score 0):

This traceback shows an error checking for updates that could be caused by a firewall, proxy, or being offline.

As far as the freeze, do you have any special file systems mounted under your ~ folder?  This includes gvfs, which may mount remote SSH, WebDAV,SMB, etc.

Also for the freeze, you should confirm it is the deep scan by right clicking on one deep scan option (in the left navigation) and choosing preview.

Report any BleachBit bugs here: http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/help